# How to create a link with CLASS in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my first question here in StackOverflow, but I have used the site many times, and you always helped me with your answers. Now its time to share my doubt, because I could not find a similar one here.

I have a flash banner rotator in my website, that uses a XML to configure the images and links that will rotate. I don't have acess to the source, because it is a commercial version.

I can not use jQuery to rotate the images, because I have a drop down menu and it always fall behind the banner. I tried z-index but it does not work on IE.

One of the images is to show a video, so, when someone click on it, I want a lightbox to open and play the video (I will use Sublimevideo.com for  this)

The XML now is like this:

```
<slideshow>
    <photo image="path/image.jpg" url="link" target="_blank"></photo>
</slideshow>
```

**I need to add a CLASS to this link, because I want it to be opened in a lightbox!!!**

So I was wondering to do something like this:

```
window.location.href='link class="lightbox"';
```

But this is not a option, it did not worked!

So how can I add a CLASS in the link at the xml file?

I was wondering using javascript, but if you have any other option, it will be GREAT!

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for my English, I'm from Brazil =P

Comment: What do you want the output/end-result of the JavaScript manipulation to be?

Comment: How is the XML loaded into the page? It's a flash component yet you want to manipulate it with JS?

Comment: window.location.href='link class="lightbox"'; with this it looks you can do the manipulation on server side, true? if so what technology are you using on server side?

Comment: As 999 mentioned - it sounds like you load images into a flash component but if clicked, you want the image clicked to load into a lightbox. That is likely not possible without taking the flash source and modify it to call a javascript. Why not change the flash to jQuery or HTML5?

Comment: 999: The XML is loaded via flash. neu-rah: This was not an option, it did not worked!  mplungjan: I want the lightbox to load the video. jQuery crashes my drop down menu...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an horrendous jQuery hack:

```
$('*[href*="path/image.jpg"]')​.addClass('lightbox');​​​​​​​​​​
```

Of course, if you know what the HTML will look like you could use a far more specific / less ugly selector.

A much better solution would be to add the class on the server, which sounds like it should be possible.